Route duplication error with Nest.js and Fastify
I'm using Nest.js + Fastify Adapter. I'm implementing a BatchController class and a create method. The class takes the annotation @Controller('batch') and the method takes the annotation @Post('create'). There is no other class that uses the aforementioned annotation. Therefore it is a single route. But it gives the error: FastifyError: Method 'POST' already declared for route '/batch/create'.
This is my main.ts, with fastify adapter:
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { FastifyAdapter, NestFastifyApplication } from '@nestjs/platform-fastify';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create<NestFastifyApplication>(
    AppModule,
    new FastifyAdapter()
  );
  app.enableCors();
  await app.listen(3000);
}

bootstrap();

This is my BatchController class:
import { Body, Controller, Post } from '@nestjs/common';
import { BatchService } from './batch.service';
import { ResponseBody } from 'src/interface/response.body';
import { CreateBatchDto } from './dto/create.batch.dto';

@Controller('batch')
export class BatchController {

    constructor (
        private batchService: BatchService
    ) {}

    @Post('create')
    async create(@Body() body: CreateBatchDto): Promise<ResponseBody> {
        return await this.batchService.create(body);
    }

}

And this is my app.module.ts:
// Module
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { LogModule } from './core/log/log.module';
import { PatientModule } from './core/patient/patient.module';


// This is import of BatchModule
import { BatchModule } from './core/batch/batch.module';



import { MedicationModule } from './core/medication/medication.module';
import { EncounterTypeModule } from './core/encounter-type/encounter-type.module';
import { PractionerModule } from './core/practioner/practioner.module';

// Controller
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { PatientController } from './core/patient/patient.controller';


// This is import of BatchController
import { BatchController } from './core/batch/batch.controller';



import { MedicationController } from './core/medication/medication.controller';
import { EncounterTypeController } from './core/encounter-type/encounter-type.controller';
import { PractionerController } from './core/practioner/practioner.controller';

// Service
import { PrismaService } from './service/prisma.service';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { PatientService } from './core/patient/patient.service';
import { MedicationService } from './core/medication/medication.service';
import { BatchService } from './core/batch/batch.service';
import { EncounterTypeService } from './core/encounter-type/encounter-type.service';
import { PractionerService } from './core/practioner/practioner.service';

// Repository
import { PatientRepository } from './core/patient/patient.repository';
import { MedicationRepository } from './core/medication/medication.repository';
import { BatchRepository } from './core/batch/batch.repository';
import { PractitionerRepository } from './core/practioner/practioner.repository';
import { EncounterTypeRepository } from './core/encounter-type/encounter-type.repository';

// Util
import { DefaultUtil } from './util/default.util';
import { ObjectUtil } from './util/object.util';
import { DocumentUtil } from './util/document.util';
import { DateUtil } from './util/date.util';

@Module({
  imports: [
    MedicationModule,
    BatchModule,
    EncounterTypeModule,
    PractionerModule,
    PatientModule,
    LogModule
  ],
  controllers: [
    MedicationController,
    BatchController,
    EncounterTypeController,
    PractionerController,
    PatientController,
    AppController,
  ],
  providers: [
    // Service
    BatchService,
    PatientService,
    PrismaService,
    PractionerService,
    AppService,
    EncounterTypeService,
    MedicationService,
    // Repository
    PatientRepository,
    PractitionerRepository,
    EncounterTypeRepository,
    BatchRepository,
    MedicationRepository,
    // Util
    DefaultUtil,
    ObjectUtil,
    DocumentUtil,
    DateUtil
  ],
})

export class AppModule { }

More error details:

/Users/marcos/Documents/GitHub/HC/res/node_modules/fastify/lib/route.js:367
            throw new FST_ERR_DUPLICATED_ROUTE(opts.method, opts.url)
                  ^
FastifyError: Method 'POST' already declared for route '/batch/create'
    at Object.addNewRoute (/Users/marcos/Documents/GitHub/HC/res/node_modules/fastify/lib/route.js:367:19)
    at Object.route (/Users/marcos/Documents/GitHub/HC/res/node_modules/fastify/lib/route.js:261:19)
    at Object.prepareRoute (/Users/marcos/Documents/GitHub/HC/res/node_modules/fastify/lib/route.js:167:18)
    at Object._post [as post] (/Users/marcos/Documents/GitHub/HC/res/node_modules/fastify/fastify.js:271:34)
    at FastifyAdapter.injectRouteOptions (/Users/marcos/Documents/GitHub/HC/res/node_modules/@nestjs/platform-fastify/adapters/fastify-adapter.js:395:46)
    at FastifyAdapter.post (/Users/marcos/Documents/GitHub/HC/res/node_modules/@nestjs/platform-fastify/adapters/fastify-adapter.js:129:21)
    at /Users/marcos/Documents/GitHub/HC/res/node_modules/@nestjs/core/router/router-explorer.js:105:17
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at /Users/marcos/Documents/GitHub/HC/res/node_modules/@nestjs/core/router/router-explorer.js:90:29
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)

**
It is guaranteed that there is no other route with the path batch/create.**
As the error is with the fastify adapter, I changed main.ts to:
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { Logger } from '@nestjs/common';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  const logger = new Logger('Bootstrap');

  await app.listen(3000);
  logger.log('Application is listening on port 3000');
}

bootstrap();

In other words, I migrated from the fastify adapter to express.
By doing this, the error disappears. But I need to implement with Fastify. How to solve this problem?

I too am facing this issue. Did you find a solution?

Could you show the BatchModule probably you are providing the controller in app.module and batch.module

I met this problem,and found that there have duplicated controllers loaded.
For Example:
AppModule:
@Module({
  imports: [
    AModule,
    BModule
  ],

BModule:
@Module({
  controllers: [AController],

After i remove the AController,it fixed
